# Why did Herman claim that there's no racism in Africa?

Tags: serhiy-zhadan, ukrainian-language, voroshilovgrad

> "Herman," he said. "What would you do if you came into a lot of money? Like a million..."
> ...
> "I'd buy a house... in Africa."
> "What would you want to do with a house in Africa?"
> "I've always wanted to live in a country where there's no racism."

Given that racism certainly existed in parts of Africa (Apartheid leaps to mind), what did he mean by this? Also, why did he choose that reason?

Comment: Also worth noting that "Africa" is a continent, not a country; there are over fifty countries located in Africa.

Comment: @Mithical Yes, that's one of the reasons I was confused about the comment.

Comment: Hutu and Tutsi leap to mind.  Perhaps the character Herman is not well informed? (I'm not familiar with the story.)

Comment: Maybe he assumes that a place ruled by Blacks would have no racism. But you don't say anything about the book or its setting and I can't be bothered googling basic facts. [A lot of Americans believe Africa is a country](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/jan/24/africa-clinton), though.

Comment: @StuartF Maybe fictional Ukrainians too... :)